# How can i make the date dynamic in this query. where when i run the query it picks up the current date in the same format as it is in the query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to be able to run the query and it will do the same as the query below but it picks up the date without entering it. The date is in the query is because we ran it earlier at that date and time.

```
 DECLARE @Results TABLE 
 ( 
 _id            binary(12), 
 TimeDetected   datetimeoffset, 
 UserName       nvarchar(max), 
 ValueOld       nvarchar(max), 
 ValueNew       nvarchar(max), 
 FS_FolderPath  nvarchar(max), 
 FS_FileName    nvarchar(max), 
 ResultID       int, 
 EventID        uniqueidentifier, 
 EventClassID   uniqueidentifier, 
 FacilityID     int, 
 ActionID       int, 
 ValueTypeID    int, 
 MissingOld     bit, 
 MissingNew     bit, 
 TimeZoneOffset int, 
 EventClassName nvarchar(max), 
 ActionName     nvarchar(max) 
  ) 
SET NOCOUNT ON; 
SET DATEFORMAT ymd; 
DECLARE @dt datetimeoffset; 
SET @dt='2014-02-07 13:00'; 
DECLARE @totalCount int = 0; 
WHILE @totalCount < 50000 
  AND @dt >= '2013-02-07 13:00' 
BEGIN 
  DECLARE @count int = 0; 
  DECLARE @tmp TABLE 
    ( 
       _id binary(12) 
    ); 
  WHILE @count < 50000 
        AND @dt >= '2013-02-07 13:00' 
    BEGIN 
        INSERT INTO @tmp 
        SELECT * 
        FROM   (SELECT _id 
                FROM   AuditEvent_IX_SubsystemID WITH(NOLOCK) 
                WHERE  _date_hh = @dt 
                       AND SubsystemID IN ( 3 )) AS I; 
        SET @count = @count + @@ROWCOUNT; 
        SET @dt = DATEADD(hh, -1, @dt); 
    END; 
  INSERT INTO @Results 
              (TimeDetected, 
               UserName, 
               ValueOld, 
               ValueNew, 
               FS_FolderPath, 
               FS_FileName, 
               ResultID, 
               EventID, 
               EventClassID, 
               FacilityID, 
               ActionID, 
               ValueTypeID, 
               MissingOld, 
               MissingNew, 
               TimeZoneOffset, 
               _id, 
               EventClassName, 
               ActionName) 
  SELECT TOP 50000 AET.TimeDetected, 
                   AET.UserName, 
                   AET.ValueOld, 
                   AET.ValueNew, 
                   AET.FS_FolderPath, 
                   AET.FS_FileName, 
                   AET.ResultID, 
                   AET.EventID, 
                   AET.EventClassID, 
                   AET.FacilityID, 
                   AET.ActionID, 
                   AET.ValueTypeID, 
                   AET.MissingOld, 
                   AET.MissingNew, 
                   AET.TimeZoneOffset, 
                   AET._id, 
                   EC.EventClassName, 
                   AN.ActionName 
  FROM   dbo.AuditEvent AS AET WITH(NOLOCK) 
         JOIN @tmp AS tmp 
           ON AET._id = tmp._id 
         LEFT OUTER JOIN Event.Class AS EC 
                      ON AET.EventClassID = EC.EventClassID 
         LEFT OUTER JOIN Event.Action AS AN 
                      ON AET.ActionID = AN.ActionID 
  WHERE  ( TimeDetected BETWEEN '2013-02-07 13:53:58.134' AND '2014-02-07 13:53:58.134' ) 
         AND (( AET.SubsystemID = 3 
                AND AET.FS_FolderPath = N'E:\Lanfax\Inbox\' 
                AND ( AET.ActionID & 32 ) != 0 )) 
  SET @totalCount = @totalCount + @@ROWCOUNT; 
  DELETE FROM @tmp; 
END 
 SELECT TOP 50000 * 
 FROM   @Results
```

Comment: Do you know about the function `getdate()`?

Comment: yes I tried that but I didn't know how to set it as ex:02/07/2014 13:00. I couldn't do the time part.

Comment: From where is this query being run?

Comment: it's going to be used in Tableau. I think it's ran in a software for faxes. Lanfax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this for setting the hour:

```
set @dt = dateadd(hour, 13, cast(cast(getdate() as date) as datetimeoffset))
```

To subtract a year:

```
set @dt = dateadd(hour, 13, cast(cast(dateadd(year, -1, getdate()) as date) as datetimeoffset))
```

Comment: I'm going to try it. It looks like what I was trying to do. thank you

Comment: How can I use the same code you have on top but to subtract one year. So instead of 02/07/2014 13:00 it would be 2/07/2013 13:00

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure I understood the question. However, if you want @dt to automatically be set to the datetime at which the query is run so that you do not enter it manually; I recommend using the getdate function.

```
DECLARE @dt datetimeoffset; 
SET @dt=GETDATE()
```

I hope this is helpful.